# Is Microsoft Exchange NDR compliant with RFC 3461, RFC 3834?

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to parse NDR (Non Delivery Report) from a plethora of providers, including but not limited to, Microsoft Exchange, GMail, Yahoo! and Microsoft Live.
However, I am not sure whether Microsoft Exchange (all currently supported versions) conforms to the relevant RFCs that other providers listed above are conforming to.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick google for "Exchange  RFC 3461" returns [this Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262986) page with all the supported RFCs. Both RFCs are in there